# Can you use a SAS dataset as a SSIS data source?

Tags: sas, ssis

We have a some ETL processes that read CSV files that are output from SAS programs.  I'm in the process of upgrading one of these ETLs and was wondering if I could use SSIS to read directly from the SAS dataset.

Has anybody done this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/791e43db-7b57-42c4-a891-697dd5ed91c7)

"You can use SAS Local Data Provider (can be downloaded separately and comes as part of SAS for Windows installation). "

Comment: I have had sporadic success with this method.  As in sometimes it works but mostly I get errors.  There seems to be nothing else available.  If I can find the root of my errors I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've moved data from `SAS` environment:

- In connection manager I choose _Native OLE DB\SAS Local Data Provider 9.3_
- Enter file name (`\..\dev` before the table name). Click OK
- Drag _OLE DB Source_ into the Data Flow
- Right click on _OLE DB Source_ and choose _Show advanced editor_
- In the first tab (_Connection Manager_) choose _SAS Connection Manager_ from drop down list you created now
- In the Component Properties tab in _OpenRowset_ write the name of the table, click OK
- If you have `datetime` type transform it using Derived Transformation Editor

Answer (score 0):

For loading SAS XPT or SAS7BDAT data files without having an instance of SAS to connect to via OBDC we used the following

1. A third party tool (STATTransfer) to read the XPT file
2. STATTransfer ODBC driver
3. Setup the connection in SSIS as an ODBC datasource and load into the database for processing.

There are SAS datasource SSIS extension available http://www.cozyroc.com offer a SAS Data connection, but they where outside our price range