# Importing directory of SAS7BDAT files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sas

I have a directory of SAS7BDAT files - about 300 of them which I need to import them into a SQL Server table. Unfortunately, the date field is not part of the dataset but is in the filename. So I need to parse the filename, get the date and append to each dataset at the time of import.

Is SSIS a good candidate for this? If so, do I use For-each loop to this? How do I parse the filename and append the date?

For individual files, I can easily use SQL Server Management Studio and import it. I can do the same for this exercise too and then handle the date when loading to the final table, but am hoping there is a much more cleaner solution.

Is there any other backend way of handling this without SAS installed? Python or otherwise?

TIA

Comment: Do you not have access to SAS at all? SSIS doesn't have a mechanism for importing a SAS dataset AFAIK, and there are Python packages but they can have issues. If you have SAS you can connect directly to the SQL server and upload the tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429187/can-you-use-a-sas-dataset-as-a-ssis-data-source not a dup but related

Comment: Do you use CozyRoc at your site?  They have a .sas7bdat extension, I believe...

Comment: AFAIK the only way to reliably read .sas7bdat is to use SAS. The Python things are unofficial and slightly dodgy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

Came across an article which mentioned R's SAS7BDAT library. 
So using that, I could successfully load all the files along with the filename into an R list using "ldply".

After some data frame manipulation, I could load all the files into SQL Server using SQLSave.

The files are very small in size. So performance wasn't much of an issue, although I suspect it can be for larger volumes.

Comment: Were you able to verify data accuracy somehow?

Comment: Yes @Reeza -once loaded into the table, I'd validated the counts for each month. The data is such that they should be the same or increasing as year progresses which is what I found. Also to be fair, the data itself is very simple. Just 4 columns - 3 numeric and 1 character. No dates involved. I'm guessing for more complex data with dates and larger column base, I will see some anomalies after the final load.