# Export data from SQL DB to SAS Transport File Format (XPORT)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sas

I'm looking for a way to export data from a SQL database to the SAS Transport File Format (.xpt extension).
The export should be possible from command line in order to integrate it in an SSIS package.

Any help to guide me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Thanks!
Benjamin

Comment: Welcome to SO, @BenjaminB - can you show us what you've tried already?  [Help us help you](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) with your problem :)    Also, does it have to be in `.xpt` format?  It appears that `.csv`, `.txt`, etc. can be used by SAS  (nb: I'm **not** an SAS expert by any means).  As for the command-line, look at the `sqlcmd` command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files

Comment: Do you actually have SAS running that you could use to connect to the SQL database?

Comment: Thanks, @FrankAlvaro and @Tom! Yes, it needs to be .xpt format (requirement by our customer to import into SAS) and no, we don't have SAS running in our environemt. We will probably buy the software Stat/Transfer which delivers the capability we need, so in-house development is on hold for now.
Thanks again and keep safe!

Answer (score 0):

The SAS trnasport format is very old and complex. I wrote code a number of years back, in C#, to decipher it. The biggest issue is the IBM mainframe floating point conversion. A note on the problem can be found on CodePlex. That said, SAS makes a reader for it that would need to be integrated into SSIS. It should also be ODBC compliant. Focus on a C#/PowerShell integration using the ODBC driver for SAS transport format.

Also, see this SO note: [Can you use a SAS dataset as a SSIS data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429187/can-you-use-a-sas-dataset-as-a-ssis-data-source)

Comment: Many thanks for you feedback Alan! We will probably buy the software Stat/Transfer which delivers the capability we need. Should we need to develop the solution ourselves, we will use your input as starting point.